# Open the manage tab on the iMessage App Store from a button in an iOS App?

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, swift, url-scheme

The title pretty much says it all. I need to explain to the user how to add my iMessage App to their phone, is there a way to simply link them straight to it?